# setOnPreparedListener in ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListFragment that is implementing MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener as shown below,

```
public class MyList extends ListFragment implements
        LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();

    }
}
```

and this is my cursorAdatpter

```
private static class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

           playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Uri audioFile = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Download/audio.mp3");

                    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                    try {
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(audioFile.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(??);

                    mPlayer.prepareAsync();
                }
            });
}
```

The problem is with this

```
 mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(??);
```

I tried the below and none of them worked

```
this
context
getApplicationContext 
ListFragment.this
```

What should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it's working, not sure if this is the proper way to do it though, basically I'm passing the interface for the cursorAdapter

```
private static class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

 public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, MediaPlayer mPlayer,MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener playerListener) {
            super(context, cursor, 0);
            this.playerListener = playerListener;

        }

           playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Uri audioFile = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Download/audio.mp3");

                    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                    try {
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(audioFile.toString());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(playerListener);

                    mPlayer.prepareAsync();
                }
            });
}
```